# CSS - How to position a fixed sidebar div relatively to a centered content div

Tags: html, css, css-position, center, fixed

Basically, I have a fixed sidebar (with a fixed width) and a content div (with a max-width).

I want the content div to be centered, and the sidebar to be positionned to the left of this content div.

The problem is, on a small screen or when reducing the size of the window, the content div must shrink and not push the sidebar.

I tried a lot of solutions (floating blocks with fake margin blocks, display:inline-block and white-space: nowrap), without success.

Here's the actual page : http://daimao.info/logique-monde-esprit?testCSS=3 , which adapts great to the size of the screen but has all the content on the left of the window.

Here's a modified page : http://daimao.info/logique-monde-esprit?testCSS=1 , that shows what I try to do, but only display well on large resolutions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example of what I think you're after:](http://jsfiddle.net/e9b25/2/)

1. Code structure like this:

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="sidebar">
           Sidebar content
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           Content
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Create a fixed space for the sidebar by adding a fixed `padding-left` value to `.container`
3. Set the sidebar width to the same value, `float` it left, and give it a negative `margin-left` of the same value

The sidebar will remain the same size and continue to fill the `padding-left` of the container as the container resizes.  The `.content` will fill the remaining space within `.container`, resizing as `.container` resizes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using padding instead of margin, seems to be the way to go. The only thing that was missing is the **centering of main content**, when there is enough space available. In your example it does center [the sidebar + the main content]. I added a smaller max-width to the main-content in addition to the larger one in the wrapper/container, and it seems to work just fine now.

Comment: Almost what I am looking for, but I don't want the sidebar to scroll :-(